# Referencing to type, what is not in the build path

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

After a lot of setting, testing, learning, i did set up a new PHP Project in zend studio 8.

everything is fine, until i imported the phpmailer and mpdf5.1 libs.
These libs drop me a lot of warnigs what i do not want.

Becuase these are vendors, i just set it to not including in build path. 
The warning are gone: Great!

But, from this point, when i try to do a new $mail = new PHPMailer(); zend studio drop me a warning:

EDIT START (formating info)

```
Description: Class 'PHPMailer' not found
Resource: mails.class.php
Path: /Fmcss Core/classes
Location: line 633
Type: DLTK Problem
```

EDIT END

It's logical, because it's not in build path. This is a part of my website, but i do not want it to warn me.

So is there a way to reach that nirvana, where i can exlude a directory to validate, but include in my build path?

Comment: just edited,because the format was unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it as a Library instead of a Source folder.